# java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Cannot set ServletRequest Parameter

Tags: jsf, jsf-1.2, http-request-parameters

I am working on a JSF 1.1 project.

JSP:

```
<h:column>
        <f:facet name="header"> <h:outputText value="Edit" />     </f:facet>

        <h:commandLink rendered="#{(Table1_var.status == 'CONFIRMED') or (Table1_var.status == 'CHECKED_IN')}"
            action="#{Table1_var.onEditReservation}">
            <h:graphicImage id="view-details-link" alt="Drill Down on the Dynamic Link!"
                    url="images/editReservationSmall.png" styleClass="view-details-img"/>
           <f:param
                name="VastuId"
                value="#{Table1_var.id}" />                 
        </h:commandLink>

        <f:facet name="footer"><h:outputText value="Edit" /> </f:facet>                
    </h:column>
```

In the `<f:param>`, the `VastuId` parameter is been assigned the `id`. Because of `var=Table1_var` I don't know where it is mapped with class. But I got class/method by searching it manually where that value can be get from:

```
public void navReservationDetail(final ActionEvent e) {
    Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance();
    String rowId = FacesHelper.getRequestParameter("VastuId");
    System.out.println("ID :"+rowId);
}
```

`FacesHelper.getRequestParameter` is

```
public static String getRequestParameter(String parameter) {
    return (String) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext()
            .getRequestParameterMap().get(parameter);
}
```

I would like to set that parameter by Java mannually without using the UI. I tried using this:

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().put("#{VastuId}", reservationBean.getParentReservationProperty());              
String rowId = FacesHelper.getRequestParameter("VastuId");
System.out.println("selectedVastuId = "+rowId);
```

It is throwing an exception at `getRequestParameterMap().put()`

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Cannot set ServletRequest Parameter
at org.apache.myfaces.context.servlet.RequestParameterMap.setAttribute
(RequestParameterMap.java:44)
at org.apache.myfaces.context.servlet.AbstractAttributeMap.put(AbstractAttributeMap.java:104)
```

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 3):

The [parameter map](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/j2ee/j2ee/javaserverfaces/1.1/docs/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html#getRequestParameterMap%28%29) is read-only. In a servlet environment this data structure represents the values in the query part of the URL (e.g. `http://foo/bar?queryValue=queryKey`.) The server can only change these values by issuing a redirect call to the browser.

The per-user read/write scopes available in the base JSF 1.1/1.2 implementations are [request](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/j2ee/j2ee/javaserverfaces/1.1/docs/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html#getRequestMap%28%29) and [session](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/j2ee/j2ee/javaserverfaces/1.1/docs/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html#getSessionMap%28%29).

When placing data into scope you should use the literal name and not the EL expression:

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
            .getExternalContext()
            .getRequestMap()
            .put("VastuId", reservationBean.getParentReservationProperty());
```

This value can then be resolved in the view using the expression `#{VastuId}` or `#{requestScope.VastuId}`.

Comment: Thanx alot ll try in min. and at the time of Get am using _.getRequestParameterMap().get(parameter)_ then can i use _.getRequestMap().put(,)_ ?

Comment: _.getRequestMap().put("VastuId",id)_ giving me _null_ and if _.getRequestParameterMap().put("VastuId",id)_ giving same error.am using it for my REST webservice

Comment: If the `FacesContext` is null then you are attempting to access it outside the `FacesServlet`. This is not supported.

Comment: there is single simple class where i put and get it's value.And for get am using FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext() .getRequestParameterMap().get(parameter) 
And it is giving me Warnning _Type safety: The method put(Object, Object) belongs to the raw type Map. References to generic type Map<K,V> should be parameterized_